# Adding a second Join with LINQ

Tags: linq

I have this LINQ query and I need to make a second Join to it:

```
var linqQuery = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
    join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id   equals c["contactid"] into opp
    from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Id.Equals(lProfileProperty.PropertyValue) && ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Equals("100000002")
    select new
```

But I need to also Join this:

```
from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("annotation")
    join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity") on ((EntityReference)r["objectid"]).Id equals c["opportunityid"]
```

Sorry, I'm sure this is easy. I suck at LINQ though. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean, but I suggest you want:

```
var linqQuery = from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                where ...
                join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact")
                   on  ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id
                   equals c["contactid"] into opp
                from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("annotation")
                   on c["opportunityid"]
                   equals ((EntityReference)r["objectid"]).Id
                select new...
```

It's not clear why you have to cast to `EntityReference` everywhere and access fields via their names as strings, by the way. Are you sure you can't use something like:

```
var linqQuery = from opportunity in gServiceContext.Opportunities
                where opportunity.ChannelPartner.Id == targetChannelPartner
                   && opportunity.NewLeadStatus == 100000002
                join contact in gServiceContext.Contacts
                  on opportunity.Id equals contact.Id into contacts
                from contactOrNull in contacts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join annotation in gServiceContext.Annotations
                  on annotation.ObjectId equals opportunity.OpportunityId
                select ...;
```